# $\vec x''=-\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta\\2\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}/r^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Let the vector valued function $\vec x(t) =\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{bmatrix}$ have polar coordinates $x_1(t)= r(t)\cos(\theta(t ))$ and $x_2(t)=r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$, satisfying the differential equation

$$\vec x''=-\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta\\2\sin\theta\end{bmatrix}/r^2$$

Where the derivative is taken with respect to $t$.  Suppose $\vec x(0)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\vec x'(0)=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

I don't think I've ever seen a differential equation like this and have no idea where to begin. It can't be solved with the matrix methods that I know because it does not have constant coefficients. After two applications of the chain rule for the derivative I see now way forward.

Comment: My comment from [your deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711176/vec-x-beginbmatrix-r-cos-theta-2r-sin-theta-endbmatrix) still remains: how is the notation supposed to be interpreted? Does it mean $(x_1'',x_2'') = - (x_1, 2x_2) / (x_1^2+x_2^2)^{3/2}$?

Comment: @HansLundmark yes, that's an equivalent statement.

Comment: OK, fine. In what [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) did you encounter this? Is it an exercise in a course, or what? Do you have any reason to expect that it's possible to find an explicit solution?

Comment: @HansLundmark I was thinking about the universal law of gravitation, and by picking units and constants so as to simplify the problem, thought about the gravity field that an object should experience if at a place with a certain velocity. I can guess the solution to the D.E. associated with that, but just guessing a solution seems like a hack move so I was wondering if there were a theory of how to solve similar problems, so tweaked it a little to see a similar problem. I don't expect an analytic solution, I just was curious, and so asked about it.